# Hyper-V CPU load discrepancy between host and guest

Tags: cpu-usage, hyper-v

I have a setup of a Windows 10 Pro guest running under Hyper-V on a Windows 10 Pro host machine and have observed a discrepancy between what the host and guest report as the CPU load. There seems to be a constant 5% CPU load at a minimum from vmmem.exe as reported on the host even when the guest is idle. This goes up as the guest CPU load increases but doesn't seem to ever fall below 5%. The VM setup is just the defaults when creating a VM with dynamic memory and a max 16GB memory limit. The physical machine has 32GB memory and an i7-4870HQ CPU. Both the guest and host OS have latest patches installed.

An example while connected to the guest via RDP -- the guest Task Manager reports 2% CPU load, which agrees with the Hyper-V Manager on the host; meanwhile, the host's Task Manager shows vmmem.exe with a 7% load:

[image]

This seems very wasteful, surely there must be a way to bring this process to idle when the VM is idle?

Comment: Idle doesn't necessarily mean nothing is happening. There's an entire OS running on top of another one which causes the hypervisor to constantly manage host/guest memory management. No to mention on top of the HV, you still having virtual switching/storage happening in the background.

Comment: Obviously, however 0% means 0%, so when both the guest and Hyper-V manager agree that mostly nothing is happening, what is the HV actually doing a constant 5% load for? Mind you, this is a 4-core HT CPU, so when Windows says 5%, that means 40% of an entire 2.5 GHz core is being loaded. I like having a convection heater in the room as much as the next guy but this seems excessive for running one VM that's just being idle.